# Bouncing turtles in netlogo

Tags: netlogo, agent, bounce

Hello i was trying to do some turtles  bounce in my code, but apparently my procedure is not working:

```
 to bounce 
  if [pcolor] of patch-at dx 400 = white [
    set heading (- heading)
   ]
    if [pcolor] of patch-at 400 dy = white [
      set heading (180 - heading)
     ]
  if abs pxcor = max-pxcor
    [ set heading (- heading) ]
      if abs pycor = (pycor = 25)
    [ set heading (180 - heading) ]
   end
```

The problem is that when the turtles move to the max ycor the turtles just cross the other side and appear in the bottom of the world, so i was thinking that the problem may be that i have a wrong configuration of the settings of the world but i don´t know how to fix it. I forgot to mention that i created a horizontal line with the patches so the turtles bounce with it. The turtles can bounce with the white horizontal column, the problem is just above the window world.

Comment: see Bounce Example, in the Code Examples section of NetLogo's Models Library

Answer (score 1):

The code is OK, just replace `(pycor = 25)` with `max-pycor`:

```
  if [pcolor] of patch-at dx 400 = white [
    set heading (- heading)
   ]
    if [pcolor] of patch-at 400 dy = white [
      set heading (180 - heading)
     ]
  if abs pxcor = max-pxcor
    [ set heading (- heading) ]
;  if abs pycor = (pycor = 25)
  if abs pycor = max-pycor
    [ set heading (180 - heading) ]
```